# Example of a Sheaf (on the site of smooth manifolds) with Nontrivial Cohomology on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, sheaf-theory

Does such a sheaf of abelian groups exist?  If not, is there a reference or a proof?  Does such a sheaf of non-abelian groups exist?

I realized recently that while I've taken it for granted that there wasn't such a sheaf on $\mathbb{R}^n$, I only have proofs that specific sheaves are acyclic.

EDIT: The site of smooth manifolds is the category of smooth manifolds, endowed with the Grothendieck topology generated by defining surjective submersions to be "covers".  In more down to earth language, I'm asking whether there is a sheaf, defined naturally and intrinsically for all smooth manifolds, which has nontrivial cohomology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The motivation for asking this is that I'm trying to understand the role of good covers in differential topology, i.e. can we always calculate cohomology of any sheaf just by picking a good cover and calculating the Cech cohomology on the cover, or do we in general need to pass to the limit over all covers?  If all sheaves on the smooth site have vanishing cohomology on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then good covers always work.  I'm trying to understand whether this is the case and why or why not.

Comment: Sure, take a circle in $S^1\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, and extend the constant sheaf on it by zero. Its first cohomology is the same as for the circle, which is nonzero.

Comment: Donu - constant sheaf with values in what?

Comment: @David, for any non-zero group $G$, the constant sheaf with values in $G$ on $S^1 \subset \RR^2$ has first cohomology equal to $G$.

Comment: David, it's as Dustin says. My point really was that a sheaf on $\mathbb{R"^n$ is at least as  complicated as its support.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified: I'm looking for sheaves on the site of smooth manifolds which have nontrivial cohomology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Donu, your point about support suggests that there be also be a counterexample of this type, but I haven't put my hands on it yet.

Comment: Though John's answer may be such an example . . .

Comment: Not even the category theorists' generalised 'the' can excuse talking about _the_ constant sheaf on a space. :-)

Comment: I like the question, but I am not sure I really understand it. What is exactly the "site of smooth manifold". I mean what topology of you put on it ?


Comment: Smooth manifolds has two natural pretopologies, where the covers are either the surjective submersions or the open covers.  These generate the same topology (since open covers are smooth submersions, and by the implicit function theorem, every surjective submersion can be refined by an open cover).

Comment: Jesse: OK, I think, I understand your question more clearly now.
You should still have direct images in this world, right?
So take the constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}$ on $S^1$ and form the direct image $i_*\mathbb{Z}$ under $i:S^1\to \mathbb{R}^2$. 
This seems like a candidate, but I admit my intuition here may be off
here. (David, yes, point taken.)

Comment: Dona, the point about considering the smooth site is that you don't have direct images.  These depend on a map of sites or topoi (in your example, the direct image is a map from the category of sheaves on $S^1$ to the category of sheaves on $\mathbb{R}^2$ induced by the embedding of the circle).  I only want to consider sheaves defined naturally for all smooth manifolds.

Comment: @Jesse: I am still confused. Namely, do you allow push-forward of sheaves via surjective submersions of smooth manifolds?  Do you allow pull-back of sheaves via open immersions (or open embeddings)? (I understand that non-open embeddings are not allowed as in Donu's example.) 

Comment: @Misha: no push forwards.  Pre-sheaves are contravariant functors from the category of smooth manifolds to sets (or groups, or abelian groups).   So we can pull back along any map but nothing else.  Sheaves are those presheaves which satisfy descent with respect to surjective submersions (or open covers if you prefer).

For example, for any k, differential k-forms are a sheaf on the smooth site.

Comment: ps. I'm sorry if that comes off as pedantic.  It's certainly not intended as such, I just want to be clear about what I'm trying to ask.  

Comment: The category of smooth manifolds is a subcategory of the category of sheaves on the site with objects the $\mathbb{R}^n$s for $n\geq 0$ with the good open cover coverage (note that this coverage is not a pretopology - see nLab for terms). Urs Schreiber calls this site $Cart$ (=cartesian spaces). I'm sure there is stuff on the nLab that will answer your question, I can't think exactly of the precise result. I'm sure it is true, because the whole point about Cech cohomology is that it works if you have fine enough open covers. A priori one should use hypercovers to calculate it, but working with

Comment: finite-dimensional paracompact second-countable manifolds one only needs ordinary covers, and the simplicial manifold that arises from taking the nerve of the Cech groupoid of the cover is levelwise a coproduct of representables when considered as a sheaf on $Cart$. Since each representable is smoothly contractible, I believe this means you find that the manifold is equivalent (in the sense of homotopy of simplicial sheaves) to the (Kan) simplicial set which is levelwise $\pi_0$ of this simplicial manifold. Then the Cech cohomology is given by maps from this simplicial set to the coefficient 

Comment: object. This is a bit of a vague answer, hence it is a comment. If you had asked the question you are really interested in, it would have been answered quickly. However, the question you did ask is very interesting in its own right! 

Comment: One thing to think about might be the sequence of maps of sites:

$GoodCovers/M \hookrightarrow Submersion/M \hookrightarrow Diff/M \to Diff$

which is the composite of inclusion and the forgetful functor. The two subcategories on the left are full. One can pull sheaves back to $GoodCovers/M$ this way, so if one had an example of a sheaf with non-vanishing cohomology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ on $Diff$, one could see what it would look like over the small site $GoodCovers/\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Hi David, that's actually the interesting thing about smooth manifolds: the nerve of a good cover is not equivalent in this setting to its levelwise $\pi_0$.  For instance, consider the sheaf of smooth functions into $U(1)$.  $H^0(-,U(1))$ is just the ring of smooth $U(1)$-valued functions, which is quite different when evaluated on $\mathbb{R}^n$ or the point.  The stuff on n-lab doesn't answer this question, at least not so far as I can see.   

Thanks for taking the time to write such a lengthy comment by the way.  I'm glad you find both questions interesting, and if I don't succeed . . .

Comment: in getting an answer to this question, I'll try again with the Cech cohomology question and see if that is more successful.  They're equivalent at the end of the day in any case, and I thought this was the more basic/concrete formulation to ask.

Comment: Hmm, yes, there are some subtleties when the coefficient sheaf isn't 'discrete'. For a discrete abelian group I think it should be ok. I only partially understand the $(\infty,1)$-topos stuff that goes on at the nLab, so I hope someone with a better grasp tunes in.

Comment: Regarding: "the nerve of a good cover is not equivalent in this setting to its levelwise $\pi_0$" - one just needs the right sort of equivalence :) See http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nerve+theorem

Comment: Yes, but we can conclude a lot of things in mathematics if we just adjust the notion of equivalence :)

Answer (score 13):

A long time ago (1972) I proved that the first cohomology of the sheaf of nash functions on an interval is infinite-dimensional.

As a specific example, consider the cover of $(-2,2)$ by $U_1=(-2,1)$ and $U_2=(-1,2)$ and the 1-cocycle $\alpha=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ on $U=U_1\cap U_2=(-1,1)$.  Then $\alpha$ is not a coboundary: there are no Nash functions $\beta_1$ on $U_1$ and $\beta_2$ on $U_2$ such that 
[
\beta_1-\beta_2=\alpha
]
on $U$.

This is proved in the paper

http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hubbard/CohomologyNashSheaves.pdf.

John Hubbard

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the answer and the link.  I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Hi John, I read your article.  I hadn't heard of Nash manifolds before, so this was a nice example to start with.  

As I clarified above, what I'd really like is an example of a sheaf on the site of smooth manifolds which has nontrivial cohomology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Is it the case that every smooth manifold is Nash, and your example applies?  My hunch would be no, but it at least seems every compact smooth manifold is diffeomorphic to a Nash manifold . . .

Comment: Nash proved ("Real algebraic manifolds", 1952) that every smooth compact manifold is diffeomorphic to a component (in the classical topology) of a real-algebraic set. Tognoli ("Su una congettura di Nash", 1973) proved that every smooth compact manifold $M$ is diffeomorphic to a real-algebraic set $V$. One can improve this result, I think it is in the book of Akbulut and King "Topology of real algebraic sets," as follows: The variety defining $V$ can be taken to be nonsingular. In any case, every such $M$ admits a Nash structure. (I do not know if it is unique though.) 

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_functions#Nash_manifolds

Comment: Misha, this suggests that there are smooth noncompact manifolds which are not Nash.  Is this correct?

Comment: Shiota proved that all Nash manifolds are tame, so yes, some smooth open manifolds are not Nash. 

Comment: @Jesse: If you want, you can define the "Nash" class of sheaves on smooth manifolds as follows. A sheaf $F$ on $M$ is "Nash" if $M$ admits a (smooth) embedding in some ${\mathbb R}^N$ so that  $F$ is the restriction of the sheaf of Nash functions from ${\mathbb R}^N$ to $F$. (One can play the same game with sheaves of holomorphic functions.) Since I do not know what the *site* of smooth manifolds is, I am not sure if this thing satisfies your requirements. You can also try to use open immersions/submersions of smooth open manifolds to Nash manifolds (use theorems of Hirsch and Phillips)... 

Comment: ...For instance, you can play the following game using open embeddings and submersions: Every smooth $n$-manifold $M$ embeds in some ${\mathbb R}^{2n+1}$. Take a tubular neighborhood $U$ of the image. Then $U$ admits a sheaf $F$ of Nash functions (restriction from  ${\mathbb R}^{2n+1}$). On the other hand, you also have the (normal bundle) fibration $\nu: U\to M$. Now, push-forward $F$ via $\nu$.   

Comment: Misha, that's what I expected re: not all smooth manifolds are Nash.  The "site of smooth manifolds" is the category of smooth manifolds and smooth maps, endowed with a Grothendieck topology generated by saying that surjective submersions are covers.  The suggestion about defining Nash functions via an embedding is a reasonable idea for studying generalized Nash functions, but not what I'm looking for.  



Comment: @Jesse: Actually, I think category of Nash manifolds is not the right one. One should use *weakly Nash* manifolds (this is my terminology, I am not sure what is the official one if there is any) which are smooth manifolds with atlases where transition maps are Nash (open sets are no longer required to be semialgebraic). With this definition, I think, every smooth manifold (compact or not) admits a weakly Nash structure and such a structure is unique. I have to think it through though.  

Comment: When I wrote "Nash manifold", I meant "locally Nash" in your sense.

It is true, as proved by Nash, that all smooth manifolds carry a Nash structure. The proof is a variant of the Weierstrass approximation theorem.

In fact the Nash structures obtained from such embeddings are always Nash-isomorphic.

But the obvious Nash structure on $R/Z$ coming from $R$ is not equivalent to the structure of the circle as the set of equation $x^2+y^2=1$.
 

Answer (score 3):

Another example, actually a lot more important, is to take a Hartogs figure, such at
$$
X:=D\times \{0\}\cup \partial D \times D \subset \mathbb C^2
$$
which your are welcome to think of as $\mathbb R^4$.

Take a neighborhood $U$ of $X$.  Then the first cohomoloy of a small neighborhood $U$ with values in the sheaf of holomorphic functions is not zero.

I could spell t out if you are interested.

John Hubbard